# Robolectric mocking network response with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, robolectric

When attempting to mock the response for retrofit (v2.1) in roboletric I get the error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.ArrayList<com.capacity_uk.capacity.Model.Venue> for method EstablishmentAPI.getEstablishments`

And the line causing it:

`Call<ArrayList<Venue>> call = client.getEstablishments(mCurrentUserLocation.getLongitude(), mCurrentUserLocation.getLatitude(), mType.getValue());`

This is working fine on device/emulator but not in tests, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Or am I meant to use an interceptor for debugging/testing purposes?